# Large AND OR query timing out

Tags: wp-query, custom-field, post-meta, meta-query

I am working on a wordpress calendar plugin and ran into a issue with custom fields.  I can do two separate queries one for repeat events and one for static events but when I try to combine them my script processes until the server crashes and restarts mysql...

```
$args = array(
    'numberposts'   => -1,
    'post_type'     => 'events',
    'meta_query'    => array(
        'relation' => 'OR',
        array(
            'relation' => 'AND',
            array( 'key' => 'calendar', 'value' => $cid, 'compare' => '='),
            array( 'key' => 'event_date', 'value' => $startQuery, 'compare' => '>=' ),
            array( 'key' => 'event_date', 'value' => $endQuery, 'compare' => '<=' ),
            array( 'key' => 'does_this_event_repeat', 'value' => '1', 'compare' => '='),
            array( 'key' => 'event_category', 'value' => '"'.$category.'"',
           'compare' => 'LIKE'),
        ),
        array(
            'relation' => 'AND',
            array( 'key' => 'calendar', 'value' => $cid, 'compare' => '='),
            array( 'key' => 'event_date', 'value' => $endQuery, 'compare' => '<=' ),
            array( 'key' => 'repeat_until', 'value' => $startQuery, 'compare' => '>=' ),
            array( 'key' => 'does_this_event_repeat', 'value' => '1', 'compare' => '>'),
            array( 'key' => 'event_category', 'value' => '"'.$category.'"',
           'compare' => 'LIKE')
        ),
    )
);
$the_query = new WP_Query( $args );
```

UPDATE:

Please help me figure out why the top does not work but the code below does.  I took the exact code and broke it into two queries and then combine them into a single.

```
$static = array(
    'numberposts'   => -1,
    'post_type'     => 'protean_event',
    'meta_query'    => array(
        'relation' => 'AND',
        array( 'key' => 'calendar', 'value' => $cid, 'compare' => '='),
        array( 'key' => 'event_date', 'value' => $startQuery, 'compare' => '>=' ),
        array( 'key' => 'event_date', 'value' => $endQuery, 'compare' => '<=' ),
        array( 'key' => 'does_this_event_repeat', 'value' => '1', 'compare' => '='),
        array( 'key' => 'event_category', 'value' => $category, 'compare' => 'LIKE'),
    )
);
$repeating = array(
    'numberposts'   => -1,
    'post_type'     => 'protean_event',
    'meta_query'    => array(
        'relation' => 'AND',
        array( 'key' => 'calendar', 'value' => $cid, 'compare' => '='),
        array( 'key' => 'event_date', 'value' => $endQuery, 'compare' => '<=' ),
        array( 'key' => 'repeat_until', 'value' => $startQuery, 'compare' => '>=' ),
        array( 'key' => 'does_this_event_repeat', 'value' => '1', 'compare' => '>'),
        array( 'key' => 'event_category', 'value' => $category, 'compare' => 'LIKE'),
    )
);
$query1 = new WP_Query($static);
$query2 = new WP_Query($repeating);

//create new empty query and populate it with the other two
$wp_query = new WP_Query();
$wp_query->posts = array_merge( $query1->posts, $query2->posts );

//populate post_count count for the loop to work correctly
$wp_query->post_count = $query1->post_count + $query2->post_count;
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all, anything that involves `LIKE` just can't be fast. If you want fast queries, avoid `LIKE`.

On top of that, basically your combined query just don't care if there is a repeat or not, so just one variation without checking the repeat field should be enough.

Now why does the server crash is hard to tell, but most of the time it is a symptom of running out of memory. The question here is whether it is the mySQL that ran out of memory or the PHP side. In any case, requesting an unbound number of results will do that to you when you have many results.

Comment: The two queries are not the same if you read them closer you will see that repeat is not the only change.  It compares a different date field if the event repeats.  The database only has 5 results so the size should not be the issue.  If I split the query into two it works in a split second but once i combine them with the OR it times out.

Comment: I forgot to mention I have to use LIKE because event_category is an array

Comment: In the end it doesn't matter if you can or can not unify the queries, `LIKE` will still keep your performance down and it is a problem for which you have to redesign you data structure, and returning all posts that match a query is rarely a good idea unless you have a very specific need.

Comment: Please take a look at my update.  It is not the LIKE that is causing the failure.

Answer (score 0):

The issue was with the initial OR I reformed the manor in which it collected the data and it works in an instant.

```
$args = array(
    'numberposts'   => -1,
    'post_type'     => 'protean_event',
    'meta_query'    => array(
        'relation' => 'AND',
        array( 'key' => 'calendar', 'value' => $cid, 'compare' => '='),
        array(
            'relation' => 'OR',
            array(
                'relation' => 'AND',
                array( 'key' => 'event_date', 'value' => $startQuery, 'compare' => '>=' ),
                array( 'key' => 'event_date', 'value' => $endQuery, 'compare' => '<=' ),
                array( 'key' => 'does_this_event_repeat', 'value' => '1', 'compare' => '='),
            ),
            array(
                'relation' => 'AND',
                array( 'key' => 'event_date', 'value' => $endQuery, 'compare' => '<=' ),
                array( 'key' => 'repeat_until', 'value' => $startQuery, 'compare' => '>=' ),
                array( 'key' => 'does_this_event_repeat', 'value' => '1', 'compare' => '>'),
            )
        ),
        array( 'key' => 'event_category', 'value' => '"'.$category.'"', 'compare' => 'LIKE')
    )
);
```